# Find by id=1 spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a table component and entity Component. I want to select id = 1 record from jpa query. Can I write 'findByIdOne' or 'findByIdEqualtoOne'? will that give me id = 1 record? Please let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct writing the query dsl you cant, but there is a 'way' with Java 8 using default methods:

Let's say you have the query:

```
public interface ComponentRespository extends CrudRepository<Component, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Component c where c.id=:id")
    Component findById(@Param("id") Long id);

    default Component findByIdOne() {
        return findById(1L);
    }
    //eventually
    default Component findByIdTwo() {
        return findById(2L);
    }
}
```

This way you can use:

```
private ComponentRespository componentRepository;

.....
Component componentOne = componentRepository.findByIdOne(); 
Component componentTwo = componentRepository.findByIdTwo();
```

Comment: Hi @vipul see if this is +/- what you want. Cheers

Comment: I am getting error to change return type to optional. Optional<Component>. Is there a chance to use only entity type as return, instead of Optional<Component>

Comment: I have used optional, works like a charm. Thanks @Brother.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Refer to the Spring Data JPA documentation which [documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) the exact keywords that you can use.

You are free to [specify](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) the query that you want a method to execute though. Something like

```
@Query("select c from Component c where c.id=1")
Component findByIdOne();
```

I do have to put a disclaimer: by providing this solution I assume that you are really sure that ID 1 is always going to exist and will always point to exactly the same Component record in any environment that you may be running the application against. Hardcoded database IDs in your application code is not something I would ever recommend.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby. There will be only one record in that table, eventually might add another record. At any point of time, there will be only 2 records. id values does not change in any environment. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional<EntityName> findById(long id)` or `List<EntityName> findById(long id)` if it's not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional<EntityName> findById(long id)` or `List<EntityName> findAllById` if it's not unique.
We have several options:
`findByIdIs(long id)` or `findByIdEquals(long id)`